# Create PHP $_SESSION['x'] on login using sqlite3 db hosted locally

Tags: php, sqlite, authentication, localhost, session-variables

I am writing an application that includes a login page (as the index page), which i would like to assign a $_SESSION['user'] variable when login is valid in order to secure restricted pages using an auth script. I have everything working correctly without the session being set, however as soon as i try to start the session from index.php, everything stops working. Can someone please explain to me what is going on? I have been reading & trying different things for 2 days now..

**db.php**

```
<?php
    $con = new SQLite3("db/test.db");
    
    if(!$con){
        echo "Failed to connect to the Hosts Database";
    }
?>
```

**auth.php**

```
<?php
    if(!isset($_SESSION['user'])){
        header('Location: index.php');
    }
?>
```

**index.php**

```
<?php
    session_start();
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <title>App</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body>
    <?php
        require("db/db.php");
        if(isset($_POST["login"])){
            $username = $_POST["username"];
            $passwd = $_POST["upass"];

            $sql = "SELECT * FROM access WHERE (user='".$username."' AND pass='".md5($passwd)."');";
            $r = $con->query($sql);
            if($r){
                $_SESSION['user'] = $username;
                echo "<script>window.location.replace('access.php');</script>";
            }
        } else {
    ?>
    <form name="loginForm" id="loginForm" method="POST" action="">
        <center>
            <input type="text" name="username" id="username" placeholder="Username" required/>
            <input type="password" name="upass" id="upass" placeholder="Password" required />
                <br />
            <input type="submit" name="login" value="Login" />
        </center>
    </form>
<?php
    }
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Then in **access.php** it has include('db/auth.php'). As i say it works fine if i remove session_start & remove setting the variable, i did actually have this working before on another script but lost it & am now genuinely confused as to why it doesnt work when trying to redo it...

Comment: If things work if you don't explicitly start the session then why don't you just omit the `session_start()`? Its possible that session autostart is enabled in your PHP config.

Comment: For 2 reasons, like i say to check inside the auth script & redirect if not the user from the session & also so i can reference $_SESSION['user'] elsewhere in the application. Checking the config, session.auto_start is set to 0, disabled.

Comment: Have you made sure you are not outputting anything before starting the session (not even whitespace)? This is a common pitfall because the session cookie can not be sent then.

Comment: yes there is nothing before whatsoever in either script. Rearranging some code, I can now NOT login while including the session start in the script & assigning the variable, which is what i want auth.php to do, however no value is being set in $_SESSION['user'] hence why i cannot login. I have tried using $_SESSION['user'] = $username as well $_SESSION['user'] = $_POST['username'], neither work..

Comment: Figured it out. The solution was not to call session_start in the index but move it into the db.php file but still set the variable after the login sql statement in the index. Also use a one liner in each file for the auth check. Now i can login, block viewing pages without login & call $_SESSION['user'] in each file.

Comment: ... probably because there was some output before the session start

Comment: I dont understand what you mean there. How could there be an output before if it is the first line in the script & theres no whitespace?